# Can I get the equivilent of Focused mail from windows mail in Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, email-filter

I have moved from Mail (Windows) to Thunderbird recently. However, Mail has a neat feature that I could not find on Thunderbird. There are 2 mains folders in Mail. One is for Focused mail (important mails) and Others (mainly ads). The filter for those 2 folders are applied BY DEFAULT. On Thunderbird, there is only one inbox for every received mails. And it's so messy for me. Can I do something about it to make it behave like Mail with as less effort as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird has the notion of Saved Searches.
These are searches that behave the same as a virtual folder.
The search rule can be based on any combination of the properties
of the messages, for example "Priority", or any combination of rules.

You may create a Saved Search based on your definition of Focused mail
(this is not a notion of Thunderbird).

For full information see the Mozilla Support article
[Using Saved Searches](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-saved-searches).